# Query from two collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find my way around MongoDB. It's the first time I'm using this database, coming from MySQL. But for a chat application I'm making, MongoDB was recommended as a better fit.

I have two collections:

**conversations** in which I store the members userID (which is stored in a MySQL database) and the join date.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e35f2c840713a43aeeeb3d9"),
    "members" : [ 
        {
            "uID" : "1",
            "j" : 1580580922
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "4",
            "j" : 1580580922
        }, 
        {
            "uID" : "5",
            "j" : 1580580922
        }
    ]
}
```

**messages** in which I store the sender (userID), message, timestamp, conversationID (from the collection above), read and delivered status

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e35ee5f40713a43aeeeb1c5"),
    "c_ID" : ObjectId("5e35f2c840713a43aeeeb3d9"),
    "fromID" : "1",
    "msg" : "What's up?",
    "t" : 1580591922,
    "d" : {
        "4" : 1580592039
    },
    "r" : {
        "4" : 1580592339
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is query the conversations for a specific user, let's say userID 1, together with the last message sent in that conversation.

I came up with the following:

```
db.getCollection('conversations').aggregate(
[{
    $match: {
        "members.uID": "1"
    }
},
{
    $lookup: {
        as: 'lastMessage',
        foreignField: 'c_ID',
        from: 'messages',
        localField: '_id',
    }
},
])
```

But the problem here is that it lists all the messages, not only the last one. So I would like to limit this to 1, or if there is an alternative approach.. please let me know.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you're not tied to these particular schemas, I would recommend storing the **messages** as an array in the **conversation**. That should greatly simplify any aggregation query you wanted to perform to find particular message(s) within a conversation (whether that's first message, most recent message, all messages from a certain user, etc). This will also probably be a better fit for how your chat application would use conversations and messages. Essentially, this is eliminating the "join" that is needed to find messages in a conversation.

Comment: I did consider that, but then I would need to perform an update every time a message is added. That's not very performant, is it?

Comment: An insert will likely be faster than an update, but probably not by much if you're updating the conversation by _id and only adding new messages. I think the benefits of having the messages contained within the conversation outweigh the slightly slower write performance: Your data is more naturally structured, making it easier conceptually to work with, and read performance is improved, as now you no longer need two calls to the DB for the application to load a conversation (1 to get the conversation, then 1 to get all the messages in the conversation).

Comment: Would the solution below be bad? Also, if there are a lot of messages, holding all the IDs could reach the 16mb limit, no?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the solution below that I see (although it's been a while since I did much with aggregation). You could run into the document size limit with lots of messages, so if that's a realistic concern I'd consider keeping a separate collection named **oldMessages**: Each object in this collection contains an array of messages, and optionally an _id of another object in oldMessages for even older messages. Your **conversation** entries may or may not have an "oldMessages" field, which if present is the _id of the next oldest set of messages after the ones already there.

Comment: Your application would then have some sort of limit on the number of messages allowed within a conversation: After that limit is reached, it would take the oldest N messages in the conversation, insert them as an object in the **oldMessages** collection, and update the conversation's oldMessages field with the _id of this newly created object.  Of course, this is a somewhat advanced/complicated design- I'm guessing that this chat app you're working on is more of a learning project, so feel free to disregard this advice and stick with what you have if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we can understand the last message from timestamp field.

After `$match`, and `$lookup` stages, we need to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) messages, and then [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) by timestamp.

Now the first message in the messages array is the lastMessage, so when we [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), we push the first message as lastMessage, and finally [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to shape our result.

If so you can use the following aggregation:

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "members.uID": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      foreignField: "c_ID",
      from: "messages",
      localField: "_id",
      as: "messages"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$messages"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "messages.t": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "lastMessage": {
        "$first": "$messages"
      },
      "allFields": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$allFields",
          {
            "lastMessage": "$lastMessage"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      messages: 0
    }
  }
])
```

If the messages array is already sorted, the solution can be simplified, but this is a general solution.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZUjG-sbJGFd)

Comment: Seems to do what I want! Only thing I have left is, I now have messages and lastMessage, containing the same data. Can I "hide" or remove the messages object? Or is it needed to perform the query?

Comment: @PennyWise you can easily remove unwanted fields using [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) stage, I updated the answer. Please don't forget to mark this answer and upvote.

Comment: I seem to miss the project stage in the updated answer. Can you add it again?